# n-tier dynamic menu based on web.sitemap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a sitemap that I'd like to create a menu out of. It needs to be dynamic, and can be 2, 3, or sometimes 4 levels deep.

Is there any quick plugin or tutorial about how to do this?

Comment: how r u creating these levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

[Css Menu Maker](http://purecssmenu.com/)